# Run Function base of Time on Background

Tags: c#, function, time, timer

I do have one function to update my UI: 
At the moment i call this function more than 8 times in my Action function that will update my UI

```
   public void CheckStatus()
        {
             this.ovl_stacker1.FillColor =
             OvalShape == MEssage.EMPTY ? Color.Red :
                        OvalShape == Message.WARNING ? Color.Yellow : Color.Green;
            this.OvalShape .Refresh();
}
```

how can i make this function Auto Run every 5 Sec on my main?
( because i dont want to call the function in other functions many times)

Here is my ActionFunction

```
       public void Action()
{
//do something....
checkstatus();
//do something.......
checkstatus();
//do something........
checkstatus();
...
...
..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To call a method every 5 seconds, you could use a timer, but I don't think that's the right solution here. (Although, for a timer to work, you would also need to have the UI thread idle, which it seems you don't.)

Instead, you should call `CheckStatus()` when you actually change the status, ideally in a setter of the relevant property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class

Comment: Be careful with this timer, because it runs on a background thread, which means you can't access UI from it.

Comment: Nice catch, I updated to point to System.Windows.Forms.Timer, which is  good to work with UIs.